# Real time plotting osciloscope/captured data

Tags: python, plot, waveform, oscilloscope

My hardware for capturing waves creates an 2D array with 500 traces of length 5000 (points). I would like to see how the data/traces look like during the computation of this array, since I move my device around and capture different waves from different edges. Im using jupyter+python for the capturing work and tried matplotlib to plot the data, although the plotting can be only (or I can only) done after the traces are gathered, but I would need to see the traces changing in real time. I read about the holoviews library, although the same problem occurs.

How can I plot real time data, when I get 1 trace per computation?

For example: I capture 1 trace of 5000 points (x-axis length) and would like to plot that one trace, then another trace is captured and it would have to adjust to the old plot. This should work like an audio recording plotting, where you record voice and whenever you speak you can instantly see the waves as they move

Comment: Please add your attempts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.